# Should $query-> be used with conditional tags?

Tags: wp-query, conditional-tags

The function below limits the search results to posts only.

```
function exclude_pages_from_search_results( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_search() ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post' ) );
    }    
}
```

Should `$query->`be used with conditional tags such as `is_home()`, `is_search()`? If not, why and if yes, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As background, there are functions in WordPress that tell you certain things about the main query. For example, `is_search()`, `is_archive()` etc. will tell you whether the main query is a search query, or an archive query respectively. These typically, *but not necessarily*, line up with where certain templates will be used.

You use these functions if you want to know this information about the main query, and therefore know what kind of page you're looking at. However, note that the main query is an instance of `WP_Query`, but developers can create their own queries by creating their own instances of `WP_Query`.

Instances of the `WP_Query` object have equivalents of these conditional functions as [methods](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.properties-methods). You can use these methods if you want to know the same thing about any of those specific queries, even if it's not the main query. For example (and assuming we are not on the search page):

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 's' => 'Search term' ) );

var_dump( $query->is_search() ); // true
var_dump( is_search() ); // false
```

In fact, most conditional functions related to queries are just aliases for calling those methods on the main query. For example, `is_archive()` is exactly the same as this:

```
global $wp_query;
return $wp_query->is_archive();
```

So you use those functions as methods (i.e. with `$query->`) if you need to know if that query matches that condition. Or you use the naked function to check if the *main query* matches that condition.

Note that there's nothing special about `$query->`. `$query` is just a variable containing an instance of `WP_Query`. So when doing that check you need to substitute `$query` with an instance of `WP_Query`

When it comes to using `pre_get_posts`, be aware that this action is applied to *all* queries on a page, not just the main query. When you add an action to that hook, the query that the hook is currently being applied to will be passed to the callback as the first argument, so you should check the conditions against that variable to only apply changes to queries that match the condition.

Comment: Thanks. Have I understood you correctly that it should be used only if  `$query->is_main_query()` is called?

Comment: No. You should use it whenever you want to use one of the main conditional functions, _unless_ you want to affect all queries.

Comment: Do you mean if I have a function that returns `return ($post_type === 'post') && ( is_archive() || is_home() || is_single() );` it should instead be `return ($post_type === 'post') && ( $query->is_archive() || $query->is_home() || $query->is_single() );`?

Comment: That example is not the same as your original question. Your original question is using the `$query` passed to `pre_get_posts`. The example in your comment seems unrelated, and it would depend on what the function is for and where `$query` comes from. My answer only applies to when you're filtering queries, like in your original question.

Comment: It is indeed different as I'm attempting to understand when `query->` should be used. Have I understood you correctly, that it should only be used for all conditional tags when using `pre_get_posts`?

Comment: No, you're missing the point. I'll clarify my answer.

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks. That's super helpful. If I understood you correctly, if a conditional tag is used with a query e.g. `$query->is_home()`, it's the same as `is_home()`.  There is a chance that it would also match a the home template. Now if I specify an instance of `WP_Query` and call a conditioin such as `query->home`, it's a method of the instance that was created and does not affect the main query. Hopefully I got it right this time.